# Entity Framework: How to query (LINQ) for data ->child-> 4 grandchildren

Tags: entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2015

I have 4 classes like that:

```
Organization1: 
    Contact 1:
        Phones:
            phone1
            phone2
        Addresses:
            address1
            address2
        Bankdata:
            bankdata1
            bankdata2
    Contact 2:
        Phones:
            phone1
            phone2
        Addresses:
            address1
            address2
        Bankdata:
            bankdata1
            bankdata2
    Contact 3:
        Phones:
            phone1
            phone2
        Addresses:
            address1
            address2
        Bankdata:
            bankdata1
            bankdata2
Organization 2:
... and so on...
```

In order to grab the list of `Organizations` with all its contacts and each contact including JUST the phone1 (where main == true), address1 and bankdata1 I have written the following inside Entity Framework a query:

```
...
    public class ContactManagementRepository : IContactManagementRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Organization> getAllOrganizations()
        {
            return _context.Organizations
                                .OrderBy(o => o.organizationName)
                                .Include(o => o.Contacts)
                                .ToList();
        }
...
```

But I just get ONE `Organization`, and no contacts.

A tried a second attempt like this:

```
    public class ContactManagementRepository : IContactManagementRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Organization> getAllOrganizations()
        {
            return _context.Organizations.ToList();
        }
...
```

It returns all the organizations, but not data under the tree (contact->phones, etc)

A third attempt (very bad for performance) was to get ALL the organizations and loop through using `getorganizationsbyID` and get the info of each one like this:

```
...
        public Organization GetOrganizationById(Guid Id)
        {
            return _context.Organizations
                .Include(o => o.Contacts)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.Phone.main == true)
                .Where(o => o.Id == Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
...
```

But it just get the organization with JUST ONE CONTACT (the first one) and not phones, address or bankdata. The method "ThenInclude" does not accept a second call. It means accept just one child under contact, but not several children.

Here are my model classes:

**Organization** class:

```
public class Organization
{
        public Organization() { }

        private Organization(DateTime dateCreated)
        {
            this.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            Contacts = new List<Contact>();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
        public string organizationName { get; set; }
        public string organizationType { get; set; }
        public string web { get; set; }

        // Contacts
        public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

**Contact** class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact() { }

    private Contact(DateTime dateCreated)
    {
            this.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            Phones = new List<Phone>();
            Addresses = new List<Address>();
            Bankdatas = new List<Bankdata>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bankdata> Bankdatas { get; set; }
}
```

**Phone** class (same structure for addresses and bankdata)

```
public class Phone
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public bool main { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key for Contacts
        public Guid ContactId { get; set; }

        //Related Organization entity
        [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
        public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Database is created with the PK and FK in correctly in place (code-first)

And now I am lost. Does anybody could help with this?

How do I query (LINQ) for organization -> child -> 4 grandchildren ?

I have read literally dozens of threads here and follow tutorials in Udemy and Pluralsight without success.

---

**EDIT**

@ Hadi Hassan

I followed your instructions, I created new classes OrganizationDTO, ContactDTO, AddressDTO, PhoneDTO and BankdataDTO.
I created the DTO for Bank, Phone and address because even if  am sure just one is main (there is a radio button at the front end) I still will need the whole list when I get the contactsdetails.html. It will allows me to make searches by country-code and so on.

I have changed, as per your advice, but it dd not even compile. I get error telling:

```
*DbSet<Organization>ContactManagement.Context.Organizations {get; set;}
Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable.*
```

I have decided to test changing the Context class like this:

DBSet. So I changes all DBset properties with the suffix DTO. Like this:

```
public DbSet<OrganizationDTO> OrganizationsDTO { get; set; }
public DbSet<ContactDTO> ContactsDTO { get; set; }
public DbSet<BankdataDTO> BankdatasDTO { get; set; }
public DbSet<AddressDTO> AddressesDTO { get; set; }
public DbSet<PhoneDTO> PhonesDTO { get; set; }
```

But the I have got copilations error everywhere.

Comment: Since you are trying to use `ThenInclude`, I assume you are on Entity Framework Core. It's good to specify that in the tag/post, also what version, because EF Core is still unstable and different builds have different issues.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev. Yes, I am using EF Core 1.0.0 and MVC 1.0.0

Comment: Ohh, you don't need to put the DTO in the Dbset, DTO is something that your project your data into, keep your Dbset as they were, I will provide you a tutorial to know more about DTO

Comment: check this article please https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Comment: DTO ( Data transfer Object) is a dump class that you will use it to project your data on, it provides some advantages, stated in the article posted above, In your solution, you will keep `Organization` and `Contact` and Bank and `Address` and `Phone`, DTO object will be created in order to retrieve the data from your `_context.Organizations`, if you look carefully in the linq query provided in my answer, you will find that I didn't touch the real DbSet. Hope this will help you

Comment: You can organize your project, by creating a Folder called DTO, and all DTO objects would be used in your solution can be their, and even you can make as class library, depends on your taste :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get your data is by relying on the [DTO](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

so your code will appear like this

```
public class OrganizationDTO
{
   public OrganizationDTO()
   {
       Contacts = new List<ContactDTO>();
   }
   public Guid Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}
   // other needed properties goes here

   public IList<ContactDTO> Contacts{get;set;}
}
public class ContactDTO
{
   public ContactDTO
   {
       Phones = new List<PhoneDTO>();
       Addresses = new List<AddressDTO>();
       Banks = new List<BankDTO>();
   }
   public Guid Id{get;set;}
   public string FirstName{get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   // other required properties goes here

   public IList<PhoneDTO> Phones {get;set;}
   public IList<BankDTO> Banks{get;set;}
   public IList<AddressDTO> Addresses{get;set;}
}
public class PhoneDTO
{
   public Guid Id{get;set;}
   public string Phone{get;set;}
}
public class AddressDTO
{
   public Guid Id{get;set;}
   public string Description{get;set;}
}
public class BankDTO
{
   public Guid Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Your query then will look like

```
var query = _context.Organizations
                    .Select t=> new OrganizationDTO{
                       Id = t.Id,
                       Name = t.organizationName,
                       Contacts = t.Contacts.Select(c => new ContactDTO{
                          Id = c.Id,
                          FirstName = c.firstName,
                          LastName = c.lastName,
                          Phones = c.Phones.Where(p=>p.Main).Select(p=>new PhoneDTO{Id = p.Id, Phone= p.phone}),
                          Banks = c.Banks.Where(p=>p.Main).Select(p=>new BankDTO{Id = p.Id, Name= p.BankName}),
                          Addresses = c.Addressess.Where(p=>p.Main).Select(p=>new AddressDTO{Id = p.Id, Description= p.Description}),
                       })
                    }).OrderBy(t=>t.Name);
```

Implementing the DTO will provide many advantages for your data

1. Avoid Circular references
2. Return the required data and not all the object (Data Projection)
3. Allows you to combine many objects together to appear in same result, for example, in the solution I returned object `BankDTO` and `PhoneDTO` and `AddressDTO` which allows your to return list of object from these entities, but if you are sure that only one phone, bank , address is main, then you can instead define these data as properties in the class `ContactDTO` and by this you combined 4 entities data in one result.

Your ContactDTO will become as

```
public class ContactDTO
{
     public Guid Id{get;set;}
     public string FirstName{get;set;}
     public string LastName{get;set;}
     public string Phone{get;set;}
     public string Bank{get;set;}
     public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

and your code will be like

```
var query = _context.Organizations
                    .Select t=> new OrganizationDTO{
                       Id = t.Id,
                       Name = t.organizationName,
                       Contacts = t.Contacts.Select(c => new ContactDTO{
                          Id = c.Id,
                          FirstName = c.firstName,
                          LastName = c.lastName,
                          Phone = c.Phones.Where(p=>p.Main).Select(p=>p.phone).FirstOrDefault(),
                          Bank = c.Banks.Where(p=>p.Main).Select(p=>p.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                          Address = c.Addressess.Where(p=>p.Main).Select(p=>p.Discreption).FirstOrDefault(),
                       })
                    }).OrderBy(t=>t.Name);
```

and in case you want to get the phone as object and not list, may be you want to get the benefit of the phone Id, you can instead of `IList<PhoneDTO>` to define directly `PhoneDTO`.

Hope this will help you

Comment: I have followed your advices but it did not even compile. I EDITED my post with the details as an answer. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: I keep getting the error: DBSet<Organization> ContactManagementContext.Organizations {get; set} Cannot assign method group to an implicitly typed variable

Comment: You should not name your DBSet as X.Y.Z , it should be `DbSet<Organization> Organizations {get;set;}` , can you confirm if the error will not appear if you do?

Comment: my DbSet is: DbSet<Organization> Organizations {get; set; }. What I mentioned in the previous message is the error message that I get in the line "var query = _context.Organizations" from that point onwards the code does not compile

Comment: can you paste the error here, what is the error you are getting

Comment: The error is: DBSet<Organization> ContactManagementContext.Organizations {get; set} Cannot assign method group to an implicitly typed variable" ther is nothing else than a red line under the word "query" and it does not compile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124778/discussion-between-rafael-munoz-and-hadi-hassan).